# How to set domain name for server inside an OpenVPN-based VPN?

Tags: dns, openvpn, domain-name

I am currently using a very simple OpenVPN setup where I connect from different devices to a OpenVPN server and then access a website that is being hosted by an Apache Server running on the same system. To reach that server, I have to use its IPv4 adress inside the VPN (e.g. 10.1.0.1).

I would like to use a 'real' name like myserver.local. Is there a way to do this without setting up a DNS server? Can the OpenVPN-Client maybe just add an entry to the local hosts-file?

Comment: I have the same issue, I would like to use the server name of my real lan.

Comment: I assume you didnt get an answer for this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without setting up a DNS server, but getting one to work is very easy and can be restricted behind the VPN.

I am using dnsmasq on Ubuntu 14.04 for exactly this purpose. Just install it and add all your hosts to the `/etc/hosts`-File in the following way:

```
# Clients on the VPN
10.8.0.1 vpn.lan vpn.lan
10.8.0.8 service1.lan service1
10.8.0.6 service2.lan service2
```

You can restrict dnsmasq, that it only listens to the `tun0`-Interface of OpenVPN by adding `interface=tun0` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. You can push the DNS server to your clients by adding `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"` to your `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`.

The downside of this solution is, that you have to add every server to `/etc/hosts`, but for a couple of servers I think it's ok.

Comment: It would be even more useful if it's possible to access the Apache Server by using the same domain name that's used for the VPN.